# openbox in ubuntu server not start program

Tags: server

Hi i have installed  last version of ubuntu server 23.10 with openbox  i want run at startup this 2 program tint2 and feh for background  i create a folder autostart in  .config/openbox/  and i have created a file autostart.sh i insert inisde of it this code

````
# Set the wallpaper
feh --bg-fill /usr/share/backgrounds/cstenger_namibia.jpg &

# Set the Panel
tint2 &```
but after restar nothing  not  start nothing , if  run by hand work fine 
this is my log .xsession-errors
````

Xsession: X session started for stefano at Sat Dec 23 10:10:24 AM UTC 2023
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/stefano/.Xauthority
localuser:stefano being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
Openbox-Message: Unable to find a valid menu file "/var/lib/openbox/debian-menu.xml"
tint2: Using glib slice allocator (default). Run tint2 with environment variable G_SLICE=always-malloc in case of strange behavior or crashes
tint2: xRandr: Found crtc's: 8
[1;34mtint2: xRandr: Linking output Virtual1 with crtc 0, resolution 1918x981, DPI 96[0m
tint2: xRandr: crtc 1 seems disabled
tint2: xRandr: crtc 2 seems disabled
tint2: xRandr: crtc 3 seems disabled
tint2: xRandr: crtc 4 seems disabled
tint2: xRandr: crtc 5 seems disabled
tint2: xRandr: crtc 6 seems disabled
tint2: xRandr: crtc 7 seems disabled
tint2: No XSETTINGS manager, tint2 uses config option 'launcher_icon_theme'.
tint2: Loading config file: /home/stefano/.config/tint2/tint2rc
tint2: real transparency off.... depth: 24
tint2: panel items: LTSC
tint2: Systray composited rendering off
tint2: systray_asb forced to 100 0 0
tint2: nb monitors 1, nb monitors used 1, nb desktops 2
[1;34mtint2: panel 1 uses scale 1 [0m
[1;32mtint2: Loading icon theme cache...[0m
tint2: Could not open file /home/stefano/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
tint2: Could not open file /usr/local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
tint2: Could not open file /home/stefano/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
tint2: Could not open file /usr/local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
tint2: Could not open file /home/stefano/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
tint2: Could not open file /usr/local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
tint2: pixmap background detection failed
tint2: Kernel uevent interface initialized...
tint2: systray window 16777232
[1;32mtint2: systray started[0m
tint2: pixmap background detection failed
[1;32madd_icon: 25166539 (nxrunner.bin), pid 10390, visual 0x557b77fe0700, colormap 32, depth 24, width 959, height 392[0m
kf.kirigami: Failed to find a Kirigami platform plugin
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:200:9: QML MouseArea: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:200:9: QML MouseArea: Binding loop detected for property "width"
kf.kirigami: Failed to find a Kirigami platform plugin
[1;33mtint2: remove_icon: 25166539 (nxrunner.bin)[0m
X Fatal error.
Aborted (core dumped)
Xsession: X session started for stefano at Sat Dec 23 10:35:20 AM UTC 2023
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/stefano/.Xauthority
localuser:stefano being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
Openbox-Message: Unable to find a valid menu file "/var/lib/openbox/debian-menu.xml"
tint2: Using glib slice allocator (default). Run tint2 with environment variable G_SLICE=always-malloc in case of strange behavior or crashes
tint2: xRandr: Found crtc's: 8
[1;34mtint2: xRandr: Linking output Virtual1 with crtc 0, resolution 1918x981, DPI 96[0m
tint2: xRandr: crtc 1 seems disabled
tint2: xRandr: crtc 2 seems disabled
tint2: xRandr: crtc 3 seems disabled
tint2: xRandr: crtc 4 seems disabled
tint2: xRandr: crtc 5 seems disabled
tint2: xRandr: crtc 6 seems disabled
tint2: xRandr: crtc 7 seems disabled
tint2: No XSETTINGS manager, tint2 uses config option 'launcher_icon_theme'.
tint2: Loading config file: /home/stefano/.config/tint2/tint2rc
tint2: real transparency off.... depth: 24
tint2: panel items: LTSC
tint2: Systray composited rendering off
tint2: systray_asb forced to 100 0 0
tint2: nb monitors 1, nb monitors used 1, nb desktops 2
[1;34mtint2: panel 1 uses scale 1 [0m
[1;32mtint2: Loading icon theme cache...[0m
tint2: Could not open file /home/stefano/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
tint2: Could not open file /usr/local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
tint2: Could not open file /home/stefano/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
tint2: Could not open file /usr/local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
tint2: Could not open file /home/stefano/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
tint2: Could not open file /usr/local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
tint2: pixmap background detection failed
tint2: Kernel uevent interface initialized...
tint2: systray window 18874384
[1;32mtint2: systray started[0m
tint2: pixmap background detection failed
[1;32madd_icon: 16777938 (nxrunner.bin), pid 11144, visual 0x55e98590c700, colormap 32, depth 24, width 959, height 392[0m